# Ambiguous meaning of 'sphere'

Tags: ambiguity

The context is about the sacred direction of Muslims or the qibla by David A. King:

> Frequently over the years other folk have introduced the factor that the Earth is not a sphere into the qibla discussion, which is not helpful.

The Cambridge dictionary defines the meanings of the term 'sphere' as:

> 1- an object shaped like a round ball.

and

> a subject or area of knowledge, work, etc.

So the problem I have is that I can't quite figure out the exact meaning of the term based on the sentence. Does it mean that earth is not considered as a sphere-like shape in the qibla discussion, or, the earth is not considered as one of the subjects included in the qibla discussion? Or maybe even something else?

I know that my question might have a simple answer, but I'm really stuck on this and as a translator (English to another language) I have to know the exact meaning, so I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you give a link to the full source of the David King text. Interpretation needs a lot more context. But since it says 'the Earth is not a sphere' it is very unlikely that it is the metaphorical 2nd Cambridge definition. It's more likely intended something like 'the Earth is not a __perfect__ sphere' (it bulges a little and this might effect true directions towards Mecca). But without context it is very hard to judge.

Comment: I would say that as a general rule, "sphere" would refer to shape when it is used to refer to an object (in this case, the Earth itself).

Comment: Sources [here](https://www.academia.edu/37957366/KING_2018_-_The_Petra_fallacy_-_Early_mosques_do_face_the_Sacred_Kaaba_in_Mecca_but_Dan_Gibson_doesnt_know_how) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Gibson_(author)) suggest that the reference is to geometry and the direction of Mecca (or other places).

Comment: I learned as a child that the Earth is an "oblate spheroid".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the meaning of the original Arabic, rather than the English, word or expression.

Comment: David King has written multiple books with titles such as [_Astronomy in the Service of Islam_](https://books.google.com/books?id=vm3vAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22sphere+into+the+qibla+discussion%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22sphere+into+the+qibla+discussion%22) (1993), [_Islamic Atronomical Instruments_](https://books.google.com/books?id=HWLvAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22sphere%20into%20the%20qibla%20discussion%22&source=gbs_similarbooks) (1987), and ...

Comment: ... [_In Synchrony with the Heavens: Studies in Astronomical Timekeeping and Instrumentation in Medieval Islamic Civilization_](https://books.google.com/books?id=YCU9AQAAIAAJ&q=%22sphere+into+the+qibla+discussion%22&dq=%22sphere+into+the+qibla+discussion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA9uOfwfTjAhVGqJ4KHWZtCJsQ6AEwBXoECAMQAg) (2004). Judging from these titles and the text snippets in Google Books, "sphere" as used in the sentence that the OP quotes refers to a geometrically perfect sphere—a three-dimensional object on whose surface each point is equidistant from the object's internal midpoint.

Comment: Also, re "not considered as one of the subjects", if 'sphere' was not a literal spherical object but the metaphorical 'area of interest' then David King's phrasing would be more like: "the Earth is not considered in the sphere of the qibla discussion". Since it's not, it ain't.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries give meanings in lists of usage and current popularity. The use in describing the earth is that of a sphere or ball as an object not a subject area.

The other meaning is distinct that of a subject area and can be described with any number of words such as region, area, domain etc. These describe areas or volumes such as contained by a sphere or hollow ball. It is used to theoretically encompass or contain or hold all the many far flung ideas and details that could be part of any given subject.

Of the non-sphericity of the earth I believe such statements are more bragging and a credit to the ability to precisely measure the slight variation of the earth's surface. You should have more inaccuracy due to your compass readings than the variance of the earth's roundness. Spherical trig is always a tough subject.

Answer (score 0):

He is talking about the shape. The use pertaining to an area of knowledge is slightly metaphorical and usually it's made obvious if the speaker is using it to mean that, e.g. he would have said "...the Earth is outside the sphere of the qibla discussion" or something.

Another example, "field" is also sometimes used to mean an area of knowledge but if a farmer said "The cows are in my field.", it'd be fairly obvious he's talking about a grassy area of land rather than his expertise in cattle...